# Difference between Cron Job and Job in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, cron, jobs, sap-commerce-cloud

What is difference between Cron Job and Job in hybris ?

```
<!-- Cron Job -->
<itemtype code="DemoCronJob" extends="CronJob"
      autocreate="true" generate="true">

<!-- Job -->
<itemtype code="DemoCronJob"  extends="Job" 
      autocreate="true" generate="true">
```

What is difference between creation/Implementation of both ??

Answer (score 8):

The following diagram describes the complete view of how `Jobs/Cronjobs` works in Hybris, we will take it as a starting point to explain the difference between `Job` and `Cronjob`.

[image]

As the `Car` needs the `Engine` to work, the `Cronjob` needs the `Job` too. As well as a Car without Engine is not a Car anymore the `Cronjob` without `Job` is nothing.

The `Job` is the conscious element in this equation it defines the logic to be executed by the `Cronjob`.
Meanwhile the `Cronjob` is the intermediate between the `Job` and `Users`,  Through the  `Cronjob` the user can send information ( priority, triggers, node,…) and orders ( start, stop, abort,…) to the `Job` to work properly and the `Job` can display messages ( data, status, results, logs,…) to the user through the `Cronjob` too.

I believe that the most effective way to learn is through examples, so let’s make one :

One of the most `Hybris` world requirements is creating a `Cronjob` that exports all the `products` of  a selected `catalogVersion`.

1. First, let’s create the **Cronjob**, in the `Cronjob` we will define the **inputs** that we will send to the `Job`.

```xml
<itemtype code="ExporterCronJob" extends="Cronjob" autocreate="true" generate="true" >
    <attributes>

        <!-- The input is the catalogVersion -->
        <attribute qualifier="catalogVersion" type="CatalogVersion" >
            <persistence type="property" />
        </attribute>

    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

2. Next is to make the **Job** to hold the logic of exporting, however creating the `Job` is not always so obvious, because you have to deal with `Jalos` and I hate `Jalos` :p

Fortunately, Hybris possesses another way of creating `Job` without using `Jalos`, we will get to it later.

The traditional way to create a `Job` is the one presented in the question, which is to create an `item` that extends from `JobModel` and in the corresponding `Jalo` of the created `item` implement the method `performCronJob(CronJob cronJob)` and make all your logic inside this method.

I have never used this approach before, so the recommended way is to use `ServicelayerJobModel`, the `ServicelayerJobModel` is already extending `JobModel` and implementing `performCronJob(CronJob cronJob)` for you.

How `ServicelayerJobModel` works ? it refers to a `JobPerformable` via it’s `SpringID` and then execute the logic defined in the `JobPerformable`.

So all what we need to do to create a **JobPerformable** is to extend from `AbstractJobPerformable` and implement `perform(CronJobModel CronJob)` :

```java
public class ExporterJob extends AbstractJobPerformable<ExporterCronJobModel> {

    @Override
    public PerformResult perform(ExporterCronJobModel exporterCronJob) {
        try {

            //get inputs from the Cronjob...
            CatalogVersionModel catalogVersion = exporterCronJob.getCalaogVersion();

            //do logic...

            exportProducts(catalogVersion);

            //end of logic...

            //return Success (output)...
            return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.SUCCESS, CronJobStatus.FINISHED);

        } catch(Exception e) {

            //return Failure (output)...
            return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.FAILURE, CronJobStatus.ABORTED);
        }
    }
}
```

3. We need to register our `JobPerformable` as a Spring bean :

```
<bean id="ExporterJob" class="com.foo.bar.ExporterJob" parent="abstractJobPerformable" />
```

4. The `JobPerformable` should be attached to an instance of the `ServicelayerJob` :

**Via impex** :

```
INSERT_UPDATE ServicelayerJob  ;code[unique=true]  ;springId
;ExporterJob  ;ExporterJob
```

**Or via HMC** :

[image]

5. Finally attach the Job **ExporterJob** to the Cronjob **ExporterCronJob** and Run your Cronjob :)

**Via impex** :

```
$productCatalog= ...
$Version= ...

INSERT_UPDATE ExporterCronJob; code[unique=true]  ;job(code) ;catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)   ;sessionLanguage(isocode)   ;sessionUser(uid)
;exporterCronJob ;ExporterJob ;$productCatalog:$Version  ;en  ;admin
```

---

Edit : http://www.stackextend.com/hybris/everything-about-cronjobs-in-hybris-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

The cronjob is the container that will handle configuration, triggers, logs and execution results, there is no logic.

The job does not contains any logic either, it only refers to a `springId`. If it is a `ServicelayerJob`, that references a Spring bean definition.

The Spring bean contains the logic. This bean should extends `abstractJobPerformable`, this way you do not define an new item. You continue to use the `Servicelayerjob` type and all beans extending `abstractJobPerformable` will be available to use in any cronjob.

In your exemple, delete below line from items.xml

```
<itemtype code="DemoCronJob"  extends="Job" 
  autocreate="true" generate="true">`
```

Instead add this in spring.xml

```
<bean id="demoJobPerformable" class="com.foo.bar.DemoJobPerformable" parent="abstractJobPerformable"/>
```

Finally you link both with Impex or in the hmc/backoffice directly

```
INSERT_UPDATE DemoCronJob;code[unique=true];job(code);sessionLanguage(isocode)
;DemoCronJobNameYouWant;demoJobPerformable;en
```

---

**BUG IN JUNIT TENANT**

Above impex won't work in junit tenant (tested in hybris 6.2). In the impex, there is a part to reference the job : `job(code)`. So it expect to have an instance of a JobModel set there.

In the master tenant, a filter or something like that take the bean referenced in the impex and automatically create an instance of JobModel (ServicelayerjobModel actually) with the name of the bean and the name of the springId (there are the same).

Unfortunatelly in junit this filter seems to not be activated by default (and I don't know yet how to activate it). So it's mandator to create yourself the instance of JobModel.

```
INSERT_UPDATE ServicelayerJob;code[unique=true];springId
;demoJobPerformable;demoJobPerformable
```

---

**Note**

There is still code in hybris that use the "legacy" system. But I think now it's not considered a good practice to create a new item for each Job.